# Why doesn't Canonical and Ubuntu run more ads?

Tags: canonical

Ubuntu, being a hunk of an OS, is not giving out Ads! I mean, See Microsoft for instance, Whichever Blogs or Websites you Visit you get a Nice girl holding a boquet of flowers and saying Windows 7, Beauty and Brain.

In My country, India, Ubuntu is so unknown to Non-Geek people that they wonder if it is some Alien Product, Why doesnt Canonical think of it? Doesnt an Ad in some Newspaper Exponentially increase its users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are ads. I'll admit they are few and far between. Techinically we haven't had a flagship release as yet. 12.04 should be that release. I think we'll be seeing more ads after April comes.

Comment: If 12.04 is considered to be a flagship release, there should be atleast Coming-Soon-Keep-Watching-Type ad, ive not seen any, The problem is When i recommend Ubuntu to people around me they will be like"-ubuntu?!-neva heard-of-"

Comment: Teaser ads are good if you have a basis to tease with. Google have only just started advertising ChromeOS on TV here even though the machines have been available for about a year now. Ubuntu has had publicity in the past but it was targetted at its base audience. I think Canonical know that they'd just be encouraging a world of pain if they tried to get the general public to use it just yet. People have a hard enough time just using Word without even trying to explain what an Operating system is.

Answer (score 3):

**Money talks !**

AFAIK, Ubuntu started with [a funding of $10m](https://askubuntu.com/q/3837/7567) and obviously Canonical won't spend more on ads.

You're mentioning Microsoft:

> Advertising expense was $1.9 billion, $1.6 billion, and $1.4 billion in fiscal years 2011, 2010, and 2009, respectively.
>
> Advertising expense was $1.2 billion, $1.3 billion, and $1.2 billion in fiscal years 2008, 2007, and 2006, respectively.

<sup>Sources: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312511200680/d10k.htm</sup>
               <sup>http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312508162768/d10k.htm</sup>

Actually, Ubuntu does have a hell of a market share relative to how much is spent on ads.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu relies on mouth-to-mouth marketing + image marketing instead of adds, which seems one of the most effective ways of marketing. But some adds will improve marketing a lot.